# Why Alert.prompt( ) is not working in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Edit: Alert.prompt() only works for IOS for now It doesn't work for android yet.
Suggestion for other workarounds for prompt in android would be appreciated.
I'm trying to add a prompt using Alert.prompt in React-Native while testing it on an android device but its not working.
[image: Screenshot of Code]

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Alert.prompt() is only for IOS https://reactnative.dev/docs/alert

Answer (score 0):

You should use Alert.alert() method:

```
Alert.alert(
      "My Title",
      "My Message",
      [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
          style: "cancel"
        },
        { text: "OK", onPress: () => console.log("OK Pressed") }
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    );
```

Link: [Alert React Native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/alert)

Answer (score 0):

Based on this documentation for [Alert](https://reactnative.dev/docs/alert) the method you want to call is `Alert.alert()`.

This may be different based on the version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, to use Alert in react native you have to do something like:

```
const createTwoButtonAlert = () =>
    Alert.alert(
      "Alert Title",
      "My Alert Msg",
      [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
          style: "cancel"
        },
        { text: "OK", onPress: () => console.log("OK Pressed") }
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    );
```

Please, follow [react native guide](https://reactnative.dev/docs/alert) to use Alert.

**EDIT** But this is working only in iOS. To have have the same result in both Android and iOS I suggest to use [react-native-alert-pro](https://github.com/nysamnang/react-native-alert-pro).

Comment: Hi there! I have tried it out but it only works for IOS but not for android. If you have any other workaround I would love to try that.

Comment: Ciao, usually I use [react-native-dialog](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-dialog). Very easy and fast to use. But now I see that is no longer mainteined (I'm getting old :( ). [react-native-alert-pro](https://github.com/nysamnang/react-native-alert-pro) is the new library!

Answer (score 0):

**Write Prompt like this in react native.**

```
  Alert.prompt(
    'Confirm Account Removal',
    'Are you sure you want to remove your account? This action cannot be undone. Type "DELETE" to confirm:',
    [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        style: 'cancel',
      },
      {
        text: 'Remove',
        onPress: text => console.log(text)
      }
   ]
```